# Libgdx get the model direction/front vector

Tags: libgdx

I have a model instance and I rotated it after translated. Is there any way to get my model direction/front vector from my model? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no.

A model (instance) is not aware of its direction or which side of it is front. In other words, even if you haven't rotated or translated your model, then you still couldn't get the direction/front vector from your model.

However, if you know the direction/front vector when it is not rotated then you could easily rotate that vector just like your model. So, if the "direction" of your unrotated model is pointing towards the x-axis then the rotated front vector would be:

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 0).rot(modelInstance.tranform);
```

Comment: It's better to open a new question, instead of asking another question in the comments. You also want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask again to make sure your question contains enough information to get a good answer.